# Ability to add duplicate suggestion without remaining flags

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

When I come to manually adding duplicate suggestion, I found it very annoying. While the flagging UI will create all the comment for me, I can't do this when I'm out of flags.

I'd like to keep having automated insertion of duplicate suggestion comments, which saves me from search, copy link and format the link with the title.

Comment: Nice idea, but how do you suggest to implement it? Button? Adding a feasible UI sometimes help feature requests to get a better chance.

Comment: I use [this](http://stackapps.com/q/2150/39093) to make copying question links a bit easier